# Index was out of range thrown but index was not really out of range

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, list, c#-4.0

I'm working on multithread program and I want to check that all threads all finished then I have a global `List<bool> tr` and when I create a new thread I add a `false` to it and at the end of the thread I make it `true` by passing the index of current thread's bool in list to thread.

This is the loop that I start the treads on it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
{
    int n = int.Parse(r.ReadLine());
    List<int> nums = (from s in r.ReadLine().Split(' ') select int.Parse(s)).ToList();
    tr.Add(false);
    new Thread(() => Process(nums, i)).Start();
}
```

and this is `Process` method:

```
public static void Process(List<int> Data, int tNum)
{
    output.Add(ProcessSums(ProcessSubs(Data)).Distinct().Count());
    tr[tNum] = true;
}
```

the problem is in one of the threads, when `tr[tNum] = true;` whats to run it throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` and says the `Index was out of range.` but the length of `tr` is `97` and the `index` is `95`. I don't know what the problem is but I really need help. Can anybody help me?!?

Comment: Why not use the TPL to abstract away thread management?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx
Basically, you shouldn't maintain a list of bools to determine whether or not a given task is running. You can use a `Parallel.For` and let the .NET framework worry about splitting the tasks up across the available cores. That, of course, is assuming your code is thread-safe. If it's not, you're going to have problems no matter what you do until you address thread safety.

Comment: @DanielMann how can I do a job after all threads finished their jobs?

Comment: It's a standard C# bug.  Google "capture for loop variable" to learn more.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee `Parallel.For` will block until it's done looping, then continue executing the code that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this does not work please just comment and I will delete rather than marking it down as it is too much for a comment and I did not test but I think it is really as easy as Daniel's comment

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460721)

```
int i=0;
Parallel.For (0, t-1, i,=>
{
    int n = int.Parse(r.ReadLine());
    List<int> nums = (from s in r.ReadLine().Split(' ') select int.Parse(s)).ToList();
    Process(nums, i);
});
```

Comment: your parallel for has problem! but it resolved my problem (after editing it!). thanks

Comment: Nice edit like I said I did not test.  I am a TPL rookie but it is cool.